# Merging m4a audio

Tags: merge, m4a

Does anyone know any utilities for merging M4a files?
Can be on PC, Mac or even Ubuntu/Linux.
Done a lot of searching but haven't been able to turn up anything.

Comment: Merging as in concatenating? Or multi-track editing?

Comment: merging? as in what, exactly?  do you want concatenated (song = song1 plays, then song2)? or mixed (song = song1 & song2 playing at the same time)? or alternate streams of the same file?  or something completely different?

Comment: Yep, concatenating. I want to turn about 50 files into an audio book.

Answer (score 4):

The term concatenate helped me out here. Was able to find a [fairly indepth post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836842/how-to-programatically-combine-two-aac-files-into-one) via google.

"Chapter and Verse" [download page](http://lodensoftware.com/downloads/)